# The domain of derivative of a function defined on a manifold

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, manifolds, tangent-spaces

For a function $f:X \to R$, where $X$ is a manifold. For any point $x \in X$, the derivative of $f$ at $x$ is $[Df(x)]:T_xX\to R$. And $T_xX$ is the tangent space of $X$ at point $x$. Why is the domain of $[Df(x)]$ $T_xX$?

At first, I read this in the book *Vector Calculus, Linear Algebra and Differential Forms, a Unified Approach, 5e* on page 311. I didn't quite understand, so I skipped.

[page 311](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4X1Pb.png)

Then I found it once again on page 350 in the margin note.

[page 350, margin note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dL7p7.png)

I can imagine this geographically, if we want to evaluate, by $[Df(x)]$, the influence of a small increment of $x$ on $f(x)$. Then we have to choose a very small $h$ to calculate $[Df(x)]h$, or otherwise $a+h$ will exceed X. And the $h$ is so small that it's tangent to $X$.

To persuade myself, I even came up with an example to help myself understand: the manifold is defined by $X=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2-1=0\}$. The function is defined on $X$ by $f:(x,y)\mapsto x^2+y^2$. Then I take the derivative of $f$, according to the definition of the derivative. We need to find a linear transformation $L$, which satisfies the following:

$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)-L(h)}{|h|}=0
$$

Because $a+h \in X$, so we have restriction $(1+h_1)^2+h_2^2-1=0$. Finally, I drew the conclusion that $L=0$, which complies with my imagination. So the domain of $[Df(x)]$ really seems $T_xX$. But how to prove it?

Comment: "Why is the domain of $[Df(x)]$ $T_xX$?": **by definition**. Your definition of $L$, usual for a function on $\Bbb R^n,$ makes no sense on a manifold because $a+x$ is undefined. Your "restriction $(1+h_1)^2+h_2^2-1=0$" does not heal that.

Comment: Your question is quite reasonable. But how to define a derivative of a function on a manifold? And I still don't know why the domain of $[Df(x)]$ is $T_xX$. I added some new pictures taken from the book where I saw this.

Comment: There was no question in my comment, and the answer to yours is in the first picture you added.

Comment: You should review carefully the definition of a tangent vector and of the derivative (also known as the differential) of a function.

Comment: By definition, if $v \in T_xX$, then $[Df(x)](v)$ is the directional derivative of $f$ in the direction $v$, i.e., if $c: I \rightarrow X$ is a curve such that $c(0)=x$ and $c'(0)=v$, then $$[Df(x)](v) = \left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} f(c(t)).$$